# Sonar false-positive on rule: Null pointers should not be dereferenced

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a sonar alert on this call `minRating.getRatgCaam()`

The alert is related to the sonar rule : **Null pointers should not be dereferenced.**

Ex:

```
AgencyRating minRating = null;
.......
if (!getRatingUtilities().isNR(minRating)) {
    return minRating.getRatgCaam(); //Sonar: Null pointers should not be dereferenced
}
```

The method `isNR(minRating)` is a helper method that validate among other things, if the object minRating is null

```
public boolean isNR(AgencyRating rating) {
    return rating == null || isNR(rating.getRatgCaam());
}
```

When I added the not null validation as sonar suggest. Sonar is ok.

```
if (minRating !=null  && !getRatingUtilities().isNR(minRating)) {
    return minRating.getRatgCaam(); // no more alert
}
```

Sonar can't determine that the helper method did the null validation. I don't need to do this validation again.

Is my case a false positive ?

Comment: It is a false positive, but it might be a good idea not to do the `null` check in `isNR` anyway. What does the `rating.getRatgCaam()` version do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a false positive because, at time of writing, the sonarqube java analyzer (version 4.2.1 at time of writing) does not support cross procedural analysis and so it is not able to determine that indeed, for the condition to be true, the value of minRating has to be non null.

This is a feature that we are currently heavily working on to be able to switch off such kind of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Now (sonarqube java analyzer version 4.3.0.7717) it's supported and works fine